# How to make MPEG-DASH video loop

Tags: javascript, html, video, video-streaming, html5-video

If playing an MPEG Dash video using `dash.js`, is it possible to make it loop, i.e. when the video has downloaded fully, replay the downloaded content, without having to download any more data or possibly just raising the resolution if possible, but this is not essential.

The standard code for displaying this is:

```
<div>
   <video id="videoPlayer"></video>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.dashjs.org/v2.0.0/dash.all.min.js"></script>
<script>
   (function(){
                var url = "./Videos/146252.mpd";
                var player = dashjs.MediaPlayer().create();
                player.initialize(document.querySelector("#videoPlayer"), url, true);
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with `dash.js` but the `video` element has a [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) attribute. Have you tried specifying it?

Comment: @SvetlinMladenov How stupid of me! I was using autoplay which has the same effect, but with dash.js I didn't need it, however, just adding the `loop` attribute has worked. After one full load, no more data is downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `video` element has a [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) attribute. Have you tried setting it?